# Javascript setInterval - rate or delay?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Does the Javascript setInterval method wait (at least) the specified interval between two executions of the specific code, or does it wait that interval in between finishing the previous execution and the beginning of the next execution?

(or, when comparing to Java's `ScheduledExecutorService` methods - is setInterval similar to `scheduleAtFixedRate()` or rather `scheduleWithFixedDelay()`?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you call `setInterval` with **1000** milliseconds interval and callback code takes **100** milliseconds to run, next callback will be executed after **900** milliseconds.

If callback takes **1050** milliseconds, the next one will fire up immediately after the first one finishes (with **50** milliseconds **delay**). This delay will keep accumulating.

So in Java world this is similar to [`scheduleAtFixedRate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29). If you need [`scheduleWithFixedDelay()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) behaviour, you must use `setTimeout()` and reschedule callback each time it finishes:

```
function callback() {
    //long running code
    setTimeout(callback, 1000);
}
setTimeout(callback, 1000);
```

The code above will wait exactly 1000 milliseconds after `callback()` finished before starting it again, no matter how long it took to run.

Answer (score 1):

This answer includes help from jfriend00's comment below.

Javascript is single threaded and so the same function can not run twice at the same time. However the setInterval delay does not take into account how long it takes to run the function.

For example, say your setInterval function takes 500 milliseconds to run, and your delay is 1000 milliseconds. This would lead to a 500 millisecond delay before the function starts again.

Comment: This is wrong.  Javascript is single threaded so the following interval cannot start until some time after the previous interval has completed. In other words, the code for two iterations can't be running at the same time.

Comment: @jfriend00 Then how does two animations in a page runs simultaneously?

Comment: @kiranvj - Two animations can "appear" to run simultaneously by either using two separate timers where one timer executes when the other is waiting for its next tick or by simply moving two objects on each tick of one timer.  Animations are actually many individual motions which look smooth when they are fast enough that our eye doesn't see the individual motions, but there's often plenty of time for a computer to do other things between each frame (including run another animation).

Comment: Yes I agree this in a low level implementation, even concurrent threads works like this if there is only one microprocessor. Even OS does multithreading like this. But in a high level scenario we can say, with JavaScript we can implement multithreading using setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [this jsFiddle test case](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/kGQsQ/), setInterval tries to keep the interval on time regardless of how long the code that runs on the interval takes as long as that code takes less time than the interval is set for.  So, if you have an interval set for 5 seconds and the code that runs on each interval takes 200ms, each interval should still be 5 seconds apart (or as close as a single threaded javascript engine can make it to 5 seconds).

If, on the other hand, the code you run on each interval takes long than the interval time itself to execute, because javascript is single threaded, the following interval will not start on time and will be delayed because of the time overrun of the first interval's code.

Both of these cases can be seen in this working test case by adjusting the delay time.

Working test case here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/kGQsQ/