# Alarms in NodeJS (without any delay)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently attempting to make an alarm system for a website that I control my sprinklers with.
Currently, I use sockets to get alarms from the client and store them in a JSON file in the server.

To "activate" the alarms, I have thought to have a setInterval function that checks whether the current time is included in the array (using .includes() )
I am very annooyed currently because the setInterval function is delays 65 milliseconds every time it is run
Does it wait for the code inside to finish before continuing? If so, how do I make it not do so

This is my code:

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408393/javascript-setinterval-rate-or-delay) may be relevant, if I could understand it (I am new)

````
console.log("Waiting for time to get in to sync...")
while (sync > 0 || sync == undefined) {
  let date = new Date()
  sync = date.getSeconds()
}
setInterval(()=>{
check(new Date()) //run the check code elsewhere
}, 60000); // one minute delay```
````

Comment: Polling whether the current time is in the array is a really inefficient way to do things.  Instead, set a single `setTimeout()` for the next occurring time in the array.  No polling needed.  You may have to reset the timer if a new element is added to the array that has a newer time than anything currently in the array.  If you keep the array sorted by time, then it's trivial to set the next timer after one fires.

Comment: How do you propose I do that?