# setIntervalPrecise(). Accounting for time drift

Tags: javascript

I have created an example that tracks `setInterval` time drift but I don't have the experience to know if it's naive and there is just really no way to do this in JavaScript. Can you take a look and tell me if I'm good to go?

```js
function setIntervalPrecise(callback, interval) {
  let nextTickTime = Date.now() + interval;
  let timerId;

  const tick = () => {
    const currentTime = Date.now();
    const drift = currentTime - nextTickTime;
    nextTickTime += interval;
    const adjustedInterval = Math.max(0, interval - drift);
    timerId = setTimeout(tick, adjustedInterval);
    callback({ drift, adjustedInterval });
  };

  timerId = setTimeout(tick, interval);

  return {
    clear: () => clearTimeout(timerId)
  };
}

// Usage
const interval = setIntervalPrecise(({ drift, adjustedInterval }) => {
  console.log(`Drift: ${drift.toFixed().padStart(2, '0')}ms, Next Tick in: ${adjustedInterval}ms`);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: What's your question? Your code seem to work but you won't be able to prevent the drifting...

Comment: Your question is how to prevent the drifting in setTimeout?

Comment: Are you worried that time drifts will accumulate in the built-in `setInterval()`? I don't think it should. Each interval could drift, but they won't cause the next interval to drift further.

Comment: Your code works pretty well for me. There are small deviations in the individual timing but thanks to your immediate corrections there is no cumulative drift!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408393/javascript-setinterval-rate-or-delay

Comment: Essentially I would be using it to take snapshots of `JSON.stringify(Array.from(Map))` at the begining of every hour and saving it to disk.

Comment: Also note that JS timers are speced opposite to what you'd expect: a timer set for X ms is only guaranteed not trigger _before_ those Xms have passed, not that it _will_ trigger once Xms have passed. In fact, the spec formally declares that once a timer's interval passes, they may "Optionally, wait a further implementation-defined length of time". So timers don't really have "drift" in the way clocks have drift, instead every timer trigger will be off by a different amount.

Comment: *"to know if it's naive"*: not sure what you mean here? Naive? *"tell me if I'm good to go?"*: Again, not sure what you mean here? This sounds like you asked yourself a question and then posted an answer or something to your own question, but at the wrong place (not in the answer area). Maybe I completely miss what your intension is here.

Comment: Naive meaning, that moment when your code works but the first thing that comes to mind is, "someone must have hit a wall here before or there would be a JavaScript function called `setIntervalPrecise()`". The audacity to think for a second it was that simple is what made me post.